# if exist check with case sensitive in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to check whether the given file is exist or not with case sensitive, out.txt(all are small letters) file is present in location where i running the script.

Code:

```
Case1:
filename=out.txt
 if exist %filename% (
    echo file exist...
) else echo File doesn't exist...

Case2:
filename=OUT.TXT
if exist %filename% (
    echo file exist...
) else echo File doesn't exist...
```

For both case it showing file exist... output. But i need to check with case sensitive. It should show "File doesn't exist" msg for OUT.TXT

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take filename from parameter:

```
@echo off 
dir /b /a-d "%~1"|find "%~1" >nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (echo found) else (echo fail)
```

`dir`is in fact not case sensitive - but `find` is...

Comment: Safer to use `dir /b /a-d "%~1"|find "%~1" >nul`

Comment: two improvements in one line - not bad!

Comment: What about `dir /B /A:-D "%~1" | findstr /X /C:"%~1" > nul`?

Comment: @aschipfl no need for `/X`, as `dir`already filters the files. Also no need for `findstr /C`, because `find` already handles strings with spaces. But will implement the other suggestions (already made by dbenham)

Answer (score 1):

Added file list parsing:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%z in ('type "namelist.txt" ') do (
if not exist "%%~z" echo "%%~z" not found
if     exist "%%~z" for %%a in ("%%~z") do if "%%a"=="%%~z" (echo "%%~z" is the right case) else (echo "%%~z" is the wrong case "%%a found")
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks... but here the script getting file names from another script as input.. we don't know the file name here to compare like "OUT.TXT". If we compare like, for %%a in (%filename%) do if "%%a"=="%filename%" echo file exists... the result is same like "if exist %filename%"

Comment: @user1553605 If you wanted to parse a list of filenames then say so. My code did what you asked.  See the change above for file parsing.